# Как протестировать один метод из сервиса в ангуляре 2?

Tags: angular2, юнит-тесты, karma

Конструктор сервиса

[image: Конструктор сервиса]

Провайдер http

[image: Провайдер http в модуле shared]

Сам юнит тест

[image: Сам юнит тест]

При запуске кидает ошибку

[image: При запуске кидает ошибку]

---

unit test

```
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Http, RequestOptions, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { MdDialog } from '@angular/material';

import { AppState } from './app.service';
import { AccountService } from './shared';
import { httpFactory } from './shared/http-intercepter';

/**
 * Load the implementations that should be tested
 */
describe('App', () => {

  /**
   * async beforeEach
   */
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [AppState, AccountService, {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: httpFactory,
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, MdDialog]
      }]
    });
  }));

  it('Should merge arrays in one with unique values', () => {
    const accountService = TestBed.get(AccountService);
    expect(accountService.mergePermissions([1, 2], [2, 3])).toBe([1, 2]);
  });
});
```

Comment: код в виде текста в вопрос вставьте, а не в виде картинок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пользуетесь старым Http-клиентом, для него делается как-то так:

```
....
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [
          UserInfoService,
          { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
        ]
      })
    });

....
```